# How to generate entitlements in xml format without xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, entitlements

I have to build ios application, but without using xcode.
Problem is in pass entitlements to application.

My entitlements file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.domain</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and xcode formats it to this (.xcent file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>A1B2C3D4E5.product.name</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>E5D4C3B2E1</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>A1B2C3D4E5.com.domain</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

by using the command:

```
builtin-productPackagingUtility app.entitlements -entitlements -format xml -o ${HOME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app//Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/app.xcent
```

Can anybody explain what exactly this command does and how can i invoke it manually? Or how can i simulate this command call by my hand?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `xcodebuild`, `builtin-productPackagingUtility` will be invoked as a step. You simply need to supply entitlements as a build setting variable in the command line.

Comment: The problem is i can't use xcodebuild. :)
Founded solution is grep ApplicationId and TeamIdentifier from provision profile.

Answer (score 0):

This library will create a xcent file you can use for codesigning.

https://github.com/sotownsend/iarrogant

Note: I haven't tested the library.

You can also grab the resulting xcent file from an ipa created with xcodebuild and use that to sign future releases. You would have to keep these files in sync as your entitlements change.